# SFML Some jagged performance in pong clone (OS X)

Tags: c++, sfml

Wondering if someone can help me spot a perf problem, as i'm new to C++. Working on pong game with SFML, just using the RectangleShape class for now, no images.

I'm doing lazy collision checking (no quad tree) but given it's two objects on scene right now, it shouldn't cause a problem:

Code inside my game loop:

```
window.clear();

const float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();

for (GameObject* object : gameObjects) {
    object->update(input, time);
}

sf::FloatRect *paddleBounds = p.getBounds();
sf::FloatRect *ballBounds = b.getBounds();

if (paddleBounds->intersects(*ballBounds, intersection)) {
    if (intersection.width > intersection.height) {
        b.changeYDirection();
    }
    else {
        b.changeXDirection();
    }

    collisionManger.correctOverlap(ballBounds, &intersection, b.getSpeed(), &correction);

}

checkForPoints(&b);

clock.restart();

for (GameObject* object : gameObjects) {
    object->render(window);
}
```

The check for points (this sees if there should be a scoring)

```
void Game::checkForPoints(Ball *ball) {
    bool ballOutOfBounds = false;
    if (ball->getBounds()->left < 0) {
        aiScore++;
        ballOutOfBounds = true;
    }
    else if (ball->getBounds()->left > 800) {
        playerScore++;
        ballOutOfBounds = true;
    }

    if (ballOutOfBounds) {
        ball->resetPosition();
    }
}
```

The collision manager:

```
void CollisionManager::correctOverlap(sf::FloatRect *rectone, sf::FloatRect *intersection, sf::Vector2f *velocity, sf::Vector2f *correction) {
    if (intersection->width > intersection->height) {
        if (velocity->y < 0) {
            correction->y = velocity->y;
        }
        else if (velocity->y > 0) {
            correction->y = -velocity->y;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (velocity->x < 0) {
            correction->x = velocity->x;
        }
        else if (velocity->x > 0) {
            correction->x = -velocity->x;
        }
    }
}
```

And the ball update:

```
void Ball::update(InputManager &im, float time) {
    bounds.left += m_speed.x * time;
    bounds.top += m_speed.y * time;

    if (bounds.top < 0) {
        bounds.top = 1;
        changeYDirection();
    }
    else if (bounds.top > 600 - bounds.height) {
        bounds.top = 600 - bounds.height - 1;
        changeYDirection();
    }

    m_rect.setPosition(bounds.left, bounds.top);
}
```

Now for the most part the game runs smooth. But occasionally the ball skips across the screen by like 30-40 pixels.

The changeYDirection and changeXDirection simply multiplies the x/y values by -1 of the speed vector.

Comment: Without a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) it's really hard to predict anything. But did you try to using a profiler? It could highlight where your program is spending most of its time or how hard you go on you memory.

Comment: BTW, maybe not related to the issue at hand itself but since you said you were new to C++, you might want to avoid pointers a bit: instead, most of the time, reference can do the same thing but in a safer way, or if you really need objects on the heap then use some RAII concept such as unique_ptr or shared_ptr.

Comment: Did a bit of c programming last year, nothing super extensive, but had some decent practice with regular pointers :)

Comment: @Hiura i had not tried that. Running it this morning, it seems to be smoother. If i see the issue again, i'll try using Instruments to see if i can find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a silly problem not related to the code at all. Flux the app that dims your screen orange at night time was causing the performance drop.